# Microphone generates sound in headphones

Tags: audio, microphone

This might be a little weird problem but i have tested it with 3 different headsets and it occures each time. All of them are usb, one of them is wireless.

So everytime some app uses microphone (TS, Discord, even Windows recording device options) it makes quiet high frequency noise in headphones. It is really strange because when i mute microphone by any hardware button on the headset or close app or mute microphone in app this sound goes away and headphones are dead-silent (like they are supose to be) when i am not listening to anything.

Does anyone know what might cause this problem ? Since it can be "fixed" by muting microphone in app it makes me think that it is not a hardware probem. Or perhaps windows automatically mutes microphone when there is no running app that might use it  and is is after all a hardware problem.

Note that i am not using any "listen to this device" option. Also when i disable headphones and use only microphone from the exact headset, problem remains.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Somethings that you may want to try:

-1) See if there is a way to reset whatever system you are using driver's for audio.

-2) See if there is a  software driver for your mic.

-3) Check to see if issue occurs with other headphones/microphones.

> > From Tom's Hardware:

"kittle" December 21, 2007 4:56:52 PM

> > "hiss like that is more than likely comming from a cheap soundcard, or from a >>soundcard thats getting interferance from something else (computer, microwave, >>cellphone, wi-fi, fridge, etc).the high quality headphones you have will reproduce *everything* sent out from the soundcard. both the music and the >>imperfections in said music.
> >
> > things to try:
> >     check everything is plugged in securely - headphones, PC power cable, and all >>other cords -- is suprising what will cause problems.
> >
> > try and reduce the number of intermediate plugs in your wires -- are you using >>an extender to let the wires reach? .. try running w/o the extender. 
> >     Are you plugging directly into the soundcard in the back of your PC? or into a >>front panel? ... if a front panel, try directly into the back of the >>soundcard.
> >
> > For soundcards - try a turtlebeach card. They are NOT for gaming, but sound >>great for music."
> >
> > > **The other explanation could be from this user Kannon Y** >>>@http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/why-does-my-pcs-speakers-make-a-hissing->>sound-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device/>
> > >
> > > "Kannon Y
> > >
> > > Someone with a triple E degree can probably explain this much better than I can, but it sounds like improper shielding on a USB cable (or some kind of cable) is causing magnetic interference. The strange thing about audio devices is that you can detect this distortion through the noise that’s produced.
> > >       Cell phones are another cause of magnetic interference that your speakers will more than likely pick up (because they have improper shielding on an internal or external component).

Actually, a friend of mine (with a triple E degree) explained this to me after my 3.5 audio jack speakers made crazy noises because of their proximity to a cell phone.

**Try leaving your phone by your speakers while you listen to music or surf the web. Leave the speakers on. If it’s properly shielded, you’ll not hear a thing. If there’s improper shielding, it’ll pick up a great deal of your phone’s data activity. You’ll hear a variety of pulses and buzzes if so."**

Comment: Try that and see if it works. Hope it helps! Sorry in advance, my first post.